# Under what circumstances do shorthand CSS properties REQUIRE separation of longhand components by spaces?

Tags: css, shorthand

I was 99% sure leading zeroes for float numbers in values of CSS properties were not necessary, but I wanted to make sure, so I tested the following animation on Codepen ([here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkoygh1h/) since I don't have an account for Codepen). The CSS is this:

```
div {animation:xxx infinite .99s; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: linear-gradient(to right,gold,green,blue,red,black)}
@keyframes xxx {from {margin-left: 10px} to {margin-left: 1000px}}
```

I then made a typo - and learned something about CSS in the process! I deleted the space between the "infinite" `animation-iteration-count` property value and ".99s" for the `animation-duration`, and noticed it didn't break the animation ([see this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkoygh1h/1/)):

```
div {animation:xxx infinite.99s; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: linear-gradient(to right,gold,green,blue,red,black)} // deleted space between infinite and .99s
@keyframes xxx {from {margin-left: 10px} to {margin-left: 1000px}}
```

I went to the W3 document for css animations - specifically [the animation property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#animation) and even though the example (Example #6) shows a `<single-animation>` with space-separated longhand property values, nowhere (that I found) does it say spaces are required (and I looked up the [double bar ||](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/about.html#value-defs) and I didn't see any mention of required spaces).

Notably, the following (which inserts a "0" before the decimal point of .99) DOES break the animation ([Fiddled here](https://jsfiddle.net/nkoygh1h/2/)):

```
div {animation:xxx infinite0.99s; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: linear-gradient(to right,gold,green,blue,red,black)} // added a "0" between infinite and .99s
@keyframes xxx {from {margin-left: 10px} to {margin-left: 1000px}}
```

I wanted to test for some kind of generality and found [another case](https://jsfiddle.net/nkoygh1h/3/) using the shorthand `border` property:

```
div {animation: xxx infinite0.99s; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: green; border: solid red.99px}
@keyframes xxx {from {margin-left: 10px} to {margin-left: 1000px}}
```

I repeated the same as above using "0" and got the same results.

*Under what circumstances do shorthand CSS properties **REQUIRE** separation of longhand components by spaces?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the CSS2 spec you link to:

> Component values are specified in terms of tokens, as described in [Appendix G.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/grammar.html#scanner). As the grammar allows spaces between tokens in the components of the `expr` production, spaces may appear between tokens in property values.

In short, spaces are required in situations where leaving out a space would result in two tokens being parsed as one token. The obvious example of this is, of course, `border: 1px solid red`, where leaving out the spaces would result in a single dimension token, `1pxsolidred`, which is invalid since there is no such unit "pxsolidred". This is true nearly all the time, which is why you see spaces separating component values nearly all the time.

In the CSS grammar, `infinite.99s` can always be parsed as two tokens: the ident, `infinite`, and the quantity, `.99s`, because a period cannot normally appear in an ident (unless escaped). Therefore, it is not necessary to separate these two values with a space.

Comment: Nice answer....so a minifier can correctly remove all of these zeroes (as one application of this)